# Android Source Codes, Custom Controls, Open Source Libraries

Tags: android

As I was googling, I found lot of codes and libraries. But all of them
are on different sites and could not find any managed site.

like for iPhone : http://cocoacontrols.com/

Is there any such site where I can find codes for Custom Controls..
I know some of top favourite like github.com, anddev.org and Im following too.

Please reply any such site that you found useful.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com, http://developer.android.com, http://source.android.com

Answer (score 1):

hie vishal, I don't think there is any specific site wherein you can find custom coding source codes. But yes the top favorite list that you have specified indeed have lot of in it.

Secondly, apart from those there are many other sites like

http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/03/15/tutorial-1-transparent-panel-linear-layout-on-mapview-google-map/

http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

and many more according to your requirements. You can learn and take their references for your requirement.

There is a lot more on the developer site for styles and themes which can definately make use off.

Hope this is what you were looking for.